# Qt Bluetooth module: working with Bluetooth adapter being initialized after Qt's app starts

Tags: c++, linux, qt, bluetooth, bluez

So I have this program under embedded linux written with Qt and using Qt Bluetooth module (with some bluez help over it's D-Bus interface) for all sorts of bluetooth operations.

Now, I want to be able to find bluetooth adapter and use it when program is already running (use case: there was no adapter on startup, but then it was plugged in via usb).

My problem is that [QBluetoothLocalDevice](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbluetoothlocaldevice.html) (which I'm using heavily) seems to be not working if there was no devices on a startup. Class is being created, but all calls are unsuccessful.
I was testing this by creating new instance of this class when new adapter is up and running (but was not on a startup).

Any advice on this?

Also, what's the good way for monitoring BT adapter availability with Qt and/or bluez? Ideally, I would love to have some signal (over bluez's DBus, I guess) when new one is becoming available-disabled.

Comment: Don't know anything about QT. But for bluez in general, an `org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded` signal will be emitted with the interface set to `org.bluez.Adapter1` whenever a BT adapter becomes available.

Comment: @kaylum thanks for that!